# Home domain links within JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I have created a web page using JQuery Mobile that has a link at the bottom of the page that goes to the home page of our "full" site.  The mobile page is in the same domain as the home page. When the link is clicked, the browser just hangs and does not render the home page.  I am guessing this has something to do with the way in which JQuery handles links within the same domain... any ideas?

For example, my mobile page is at "http://somedomain/m/index.php".  On this page, it links to "http://somedomain/index.php" like this:

```
<a href="http://somedomain/">View full site</a>
```

Should I be handling this link differently?  If I insert a URL to an outside domain, it works just fine.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this `<a href="http://somedomain/" data-ajax="false" >View full site</a>`

By default,if the link is from the same domain,jqm will try to load it via ajax.Here in this case it should not be loaded via AJAX.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Glad to be of help.If you think my post has answered your query,please mark it as the correct answer by clicking on the right mark near to my post.